# React Native Animated If function

Tags: react-native

```
const OFFSET = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
const LOGO_ANIM_INTERPOLATE = OFFSET.interpolate({
inputRange: [-100,0],
outputRange: [ WINDOW_WIDTH/2-35,0],
extrapolate: 'clamp',
})


if (LOGO_ANIM_INTERPOLATE === WINDOW_WIDTH/2-35) {
alert('OK');
} else {
}

-----------
```

> OnScroll in ScrollView

```
onScroll={
Animated.event(
[{nativeEvent: {
contentOffset: {
y: OFFSET,
},
},
}],
{ useNativeDriver: false },
)}

--------
```

An object move to the right accordingly Scroll y-offset.
If object get x-position = WINDOW_WIDTH/2-35 I want alert('OK');

IF function not working! Why?